# How to call a remote jar?

Tags: jar

A newbie to Java, so please excuse my wording.

Currently, on one server, I have a java wrapper around a 3rd party jar file.  I am using: Class lc = Class.forName("pkg.lib") to initialize the class.

I need to put this 3rd party jar on a separate server.  How can my java application on Server 1 call the 3rd party jar on Server 2?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Java RMI](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136424.html) or maybe use web services to publish some of your functionality on server 2 and consume that web service from server 1. If you can give an example of your use case we can try to improve the solution even more in case this one already does not give any hints.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of approaches you might try:

1. Implement a web-service API on Server 2, such that the code on Server 1 can call some URL on Server 2 which will trigger it to invoke your third-party JAR and then return the result (as JSON, or XML, or a serialized Object format, or what have you).
2. You can [use JMX/RMI](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?54074-JMX-remote-MBean-invocation-via-RMI) to perform a remote method invocation and get a serialized copy of the result sent back to you.
3. You can use [JMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service) to dispatch a message from Server 1 to Server 2, and have a listener on Server 2 that receives the message and dispatches a result message back to Server 1.
4. Or if you feel like a challenge, you can implement your own custom communication protocol to be used between Server 1 and Server 2, and make it do whatever you want.  You might arrive at something similar to [RTMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol), which supports bidirectional remote-procedure invocations.